# Adding a websocket operation in APIM with powershell at root level

Tags: powershell, signalr, handshake

I am trying to import a Websocket Api through Az scripts.

As described in Microsoft doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/websocket-api?tabs=portal), this api contains a method onHandshake at root level.

```
$operationDst = New-AzApiManagementOperation 
   -Context $apimDstContext 
   -ApiId $fullApiId 
   -ApiRevision $api.ApiRevision 
   -Name $operation.Name 
   -OperationId $operation.OperationId 
   -Method $operation.Method 
   -Description $opDescription 
   -UrlTemplate $urlTemplate 
   -Request $requestDst 
   -Responses $responsesDst 
   -Debug -Verbose -ErrorAction Break;
```

Problem is when importing this method the -urltemplate param value is "" and I keep receiving this error :

```
System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'UrlTemplate'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
```

I tried setting it to $null for no better and "/" which then gives me this error :

```
"Operation entity cannot be defined by user for web socket api type."
```

Comment: Here is link to the template page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/quickstart-arm-template

Comment: I don't see anything related to the problem in your link, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: You error says "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'UrlTemplate'. What template are you using?  Link shows how to create a template.

Comment: found out the method was automatically added so it's fine, but just to let you know, the -UrlTemplate corresponds to the controller's path

Answer (score 0):

Actually the onHandshake method is automatically added when creating a Websocket Api.
So I should just ignore the import of that method

Comment: What did you change to fix issue?

Comment: nothing, the method is automatically added when creating an api of type websocket, I didn't have to recreate it manually, so just added a condition in my script to ignore that case

Comment: What was wrong with posted code that gave error?